# Multidimensional ArrayList -> Flatten -> Activation Function -> Deflat -> Multidimensional ArrayList?

Tags: java, algorithm, list, serialization, data-structures

In java, how can I flatten a multidimensional array, pass it into an activation function, and retrieve the original hierarchy from the response array in the most efficient manner?

For instance, the raw data block is in the format of

Input data structure:

```
[[.,.,.,.,.,],
[.,.,.],
[.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.],
[.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.]]
```

The activation function defined can process the entire block in a single go, so for maximum efficiency I want to flatten it in some manner.
Intermediate data structure:

```
[.,.,.,.,.,.,. ... ]
```

Then, I want to 'deflat' the response so that it reflects the original hierarchy.

Output data structure:

```
[[.,.,.,.,.,],
[.,.,.],
[.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.],
[.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.]]
```

The activation function is assumed to process sequentially so the order will not be messed up.
What is the quickest way in Java that I can implement the same? I do not want to maintain indices for flattening and deflattening if I use arrays.

Comment: Just remember the topology - the length of any inner array, then you can reconstruct the results, in your example, you need to remember [5,3,9,8]

Comment: I figured as much, but I really do not want to maintain indices for the same. Is there an alternate way/framework defined in java that can do this for me?

Comment: what do you mean by "most efficient"? the one with the best performance? the one that uses the least memory? or the one that is the least work for you?

Comment: I need this to go on a live project tomorrow, and I need it to be as fast as possible. Memory is not an issue.

Comment: Does it **need** to be an array? Can it be a `List` or `Iterator`? If so you could implement a `List`/`Iterator` over the original array quite easily.

Answer (score 0):

If a `List` is acceptable instead of an array you could wrap the array in a `List`.

This implemebts a `List` with `get` and `set` and also implements a `find` to allow you to discover where an element at a specific index should appear in the array.

```
static class Point {
    final int x, y;

    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}

static class Flattened<T> extends AbstractList<T> implements List<T> {
    private final T[][] subject;
    private final int flattenedLength;

    public Flattened(T[][] subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
        int flattenedLength = 0;
        for (T[] a : subject) {
            flattenedLength += a.length;
        }
        this.flattenedLength = flattenedLength;
    }

    @Override
    public T get(int index) {
        Point p = find(index);
        return subject[p.x][p.y];
    }

    @Override
    public T set(int index, T it) {
        Point p = find(index);
        T was = subject[p.x][p.y];
        subject[p.x][p.y] = it;
        return was;
    }

    public Point find(int index) {
        int pos = 0;
        // Walk the array to get the right row.
        for(int row = 0; row < subject.length; row++) {
            if(pos + subject[row].length <= index) {
                // Skip this row.
                pos += subject[row].length;
            } else {
                // Found it!!
                return new Point(row,index-pos);
            }
        }
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("No item at position "+index);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return flattenedLength;
    }
}

public void test() {
    Integer[][] a = {
            {1},
            {2, 3, 4, 5},
            {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
    };
    List<Integer> flat = new Flattened<>(a);
    System.out.println(flat);
}
```